# Transferring SQL to NHibernate Criteria APi

Tags: sql, nhibernate

I have this SQL here that needs to be transferred to NHibernate Criteria API:

```
select nn.* from NetworkNumber nn 
inner join
(select number, max(Version) ver
from NetworkNumber 
group by number) b on b.number=nn.number
and b.ver=nn.version
```

If anyone has a good knowledge of it, I'd appreciate a lot. In the meantime - I'll keep trying and post back results (if any)..

**Edit:**
So far I've got this:

```
var results = StagingSessionFactory.OpenSession()
            .CreateCriteria<NetworkNumber>()
            .SetProjection(
                Projections.ProjectionList()
                    .Add(Projections.Property("Number"), "Number")
                    .Add(Projections.Max("Version"), "Version")
                    .Add(Projections.GroupProperty("Number"), "Number")
                )
            .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof(NetworkNumber)))        
            .List<NetworkNumber>();
```

Which gives me the right Version/Number of the NetworkNumber, but I need the rest of the fields (Id, etc). Perhaps I am missing just a little something?

Comment: "Transferring" SQL to Criteria is usually a bad idea, as they have very different usages. Instead, start from the business requirement (*"I need to pull out latest version of all NetworkNumber objects"* or something like that)

Comment: You could pretty much use that SQL if you switched to HQL instead of Criteria api.

Comment: Agreed, hql is almost always a better choice for this sort of thing...complex operations are not the Criteria API's strong point.

Comment: As Diego Mijelshon said, the goal of this is to pull out the latest version of all NetworkNumber objects. So far I've managed to not use any HQL and would prefer not use any as a lot of folks here do not know much about NHibernate and I want to introduce them to it step by step. I thought this would be a simplistic query, but I am wrong! ;)

Comment: I had the similar problem with NH 4.0. Switched to QueryOver. But it has a limitation for subqueries that cannot return many columns as we can in SQL. try to get two QueryOver results and then in C#/VB.net, loop IList object or use LINQ query to merge the results as required.